# How should i remove printer image on print?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am printing receipt using following code,but when i click print even printer image is shown in preview and print.My code is

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">
    <div align="justify">Print</div>
</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
///all code are in html body tag
```

pls check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eugenenf/x5J7Y/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

**CSS**

```css
@media print {
    .print_img {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

---

**Update after OP's comment**

change you HTML

```html
<div class="print_img">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
        <div align="justify">Print</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/x5J7Y/)</kbd>

Comment: @user3067299 check updated answer with [fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/x5J7Y/).

Comment: @user3067299 see-->http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/x5J7Y/4/ you need to add this code `<style>
        @media print {
            .print_img {
                display:none;
            }
        }
    </style>`

Comment: Hello one more q when i click print it redirects to print in same window thus loosing original receipt.What shouls i add so that it opens in new window.thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could just do it with CSS media queries:

```
@media print {

   .hide-on-print{
      display:none;
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "strucked", but in case you need some more help, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XY9jX/

Comment: yes i am putting this `@media print {.hide-on-print{display:none;}}` in my style.css but nothing changed.am i somewhere wrong here?

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry, but it works for me (Chrome,FF,Opera,IE). I'll let you know if I have another idea. I'm not quite sure, if I understand what you want, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<button class="printbtn" >Print </button>

  <style>
@media print
  {
  .printbtn {display: none;}
  }
@media screen
  {
  .printbtn {display: block;}
  }
</style>
```

Comment: i havent added onlcik onclick="myFunction()" i thought u will do urself.